# PHP In Javascript via AJAX & Async

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

To my understanding AJAX makes javascript asynchronous. I am new to AJAX, but noticed when creating scripts to the html document there is an attribute for async for scripts. Do these do the same thing as AJAX or am I wishfully thinking. I would find it very useful to use php within my already existing javascript file used in DOM generation. Why? To make life easier and as OO as possible. The only real thing I want out of this is to use php to output my php file generated from javascript, but later I would like to generate php directly using javascript methods.

**index.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jWebKit.js"></script>

<script>

     var div = new Div();
     div.setPosition(Div.FIXED);
     div.setBounds(100,0,100,100);
     div.horizontalAlign(Div.LEFT);
     div.setPosition(Div.RELATIVE);

 </script>
```

**jWebKit.js**

```
    var head;
var body;
var jScript;
var devScript;
var phpScript;

(function(){

    document.open();

    jScript = document.createElement("script");
    jScript.src = "jWebKit.js";
    jScript.type = "text/javascript";


    devScript = document.createElement("script");

    phpScript = document.createElement("script");
    php.type = "text/javascript";
    php.text = 'document.write("<?php fopen("testfile.php", "w") ;?>");'; // This is the target script needed for file output below...
    phpScript.async = 'true';


}());

window.onload = function(){

    var cutScript;

    head = document.head;
    body = document.body;

    cutScript = head.innerHTML.toString().replace(jScript.outerHTML.toString(),'');



    devScript.text = phpScript.innerHTML.toString() + cutScript.replace('<script>', '').replace('</script>','');//Does not work!

    body.appendChild(devScript);
    head.innerHTML = head.innerHTML.toString().replace(cutScript,'');



    alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML);

    document.close();


};

function Div(){

    Div.STATIC = 'static';
    Div.ABSOLUTE = 'absolute';
    Div.RELATIVE = 'relative';
    Div.FIXED = 'fixed';
    Div.SOLID = 'solid';
    Div.DOTTED = 'dotted';
    Div.LEFT = 0;
    Div.CENTER = 1;
    Div.RIGHT = 2;
    Div.TOP = 0;
    Div.MIDDLE = 1;
    Div.BOTTOM = 2;

    var ELEMENT;
    var CSS;

    var horizontalAlign;
    var verticalAlign;

    var colorQueue;



    (function() {

        this.div = document.createElement('div');

        ELEMENT = this.div;
        CSS = this.div.style;

        CSS.border = '1px solid black';

        document.body.appendChild(this.div);

    }());

    this.setPosition = function(postype){

        if(!horizontalAlign && !verticalAlign){

            CSS.position = postype;

        }


    }

    this.setBounds = function(x,y,width,height){

        CSS.left = x + 'px';
        CSS.top = y + 'px';
        CSS.width = width + 'px';
        CSS.height = height + 'px';

    }

    this.setColorQueue = function(r,g,b){

        colorQueue = 'rgb(' + new Array(r,g,b) + ')';
        alert(colorQueue);

    }

    this.horizontalAlign = function(horiz){

        var freeSpaceX = ((window.innerWidth - ELEMENT.offsetWidth) / 2);
        var defPadding = '8px';
        var defPaddingCenter;
        var defPaddingRight;
        var defPaddingLeft;

        horizontalAlign = true;

        this.setBounds(0,0,100,100);

        if(CSS.position == 'relative' || CSS.position == 'absolute'){

            CSS.position = 'absolute';
            defPaddingCenter = 12;
            defPaddingRight = 4;
            defPaddingLeft = 8;



        }else if(CSS.position == 'fixed'){

            defPaddingCenter = 4;
            defPaddingRight = 4;
            defPaddingLeft = 8;

        }

        if(horiz == 0){

            if(!verticalAlign){
                CSS.marginTop = defPadding;
            }CSS.marginLeft = defPaddingLeft + 'px';

        }else if(horiz == 1){

            if(!verticalAlign){
                CSS.marginTop = defPadding;
            }CSS.marginLeft = freeSpaceX - defPaddingCenter + 'px';

        }else if(horiz == 2){

            if(!verticalAlign){
                CSS.marginTop = defPadding;
            }CSS.marginLeft = (freeSpaceX - defPaddingRight) * 2 + 'px';

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot generate php from javascript, you must understand that php is server side and javascript is client side.

Comment: @stalin Then I have been mislead http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/javascript/39278-php-inside-javascript.html.

Comment: apparently you did it, see the comment #3 'JavaScript cannot directly execute serverside code'

Comment: @stalin "directly" what does he mean by that. I just assumed it meant it could be done indirectly using AJAX.

Comment: Never mind I just read another article on it from this blog. Looks like it just calls an external page outside of the actual .js file. Not what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to do, but you are creating a php script that never go to the server, for that reason will never execute (only the server understand php script) if you wanna call the url `testfile.php` the you should do something like this

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","testfile.php?q=something",true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  //the responseText have the server response
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

see this site for more info

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

See the next chapter too on the link

By the way, jquery will help you alot with all

Comment: Thanks for the help. If anything I now understand xml and AJAX more :).